# image search with google

Tags: image, google-api

Google had a beautiful API which you can use to search for large images, but unfortunately they decided to disable it. Now you can use their "custom search engine", but it doesn't get even close to what that old API could do. For a start, the results you get are not the same as if you search in the common search page with your browser, and you can't specify the size of the images you are searching for.

Is it there any programatically way I can get a list of the URLs of the images I would find in the common search google page, size included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scrapping the google image search results and parse the links to the images. urllib2 library in python can help you here.

Comment: The problem is that google search uses javascript to load its page. So, if I try to download the page to scrap the urls, I can't get them because they haven't been loaded yet.

Comment: You can use google-image-scraper (node module) to scrap the images
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-images-scraper